# C++ - put expression to register and use it in assembly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline-assembly

How to resolve expression and put it in the register, use it in inline assembly and even use it again and put it somewhere?

For example:

```
EAX=a[i]; //Any expression that valid in C++
__asm xor eax,0xFFFF //Do something with this
b[i]=EAX; //And then put it in some variable.
```

By the way, the reason is for performance.

Comment: Depends on the compiler. Documentation for [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), [GCC again](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html). But these days compilers can optimize code into assembly better than you, most of the time.

Comment: Odds are, compiler smarter than you and `b[i] = a[i] xor 0xfff;` is way to go.

Comment: @DCoder Yeah I know it. I saw in the disassembly and I can make a better code. (Combine 3 actions to one that does those 3 actions.)

Comment: @elmigranto This was just an example man =\.

Comment: @DividedByZero, paste real code then.

Comment: @elmigranto Real code'll not change a thing ,I just need to know how to use CPU's registers like variables or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Several compilers have compiler specific ways of accomplishing this. But it's almost never worth doing.

There are a list of reasons why this is almost never worth doing:

- The compiler will usually generate better code than you can write most of the time.
- Even if it doesn't, you can frequently tweak your code slightly to convince the compiler to write code that's at least as good as you could write, and still have your program remain portable.
- The code that has the perceived performance issue is not actually critical to performance because the program spends 0.01% of it's time there.
- You want your program to stay standard C++ and don't want to clutter it with tons of `#ifdef` guards.

The example you've shown is not very compelling.